# Why is the drum of my washing machine loose eve after repairs?

Tags: doors

Why is the drum of my Kenmore 1102002201 from 2011 still loose, although I installed new suspension rods? It is totally loose and with every single spin all over the place just not balanced in the center?
Why is there water inside of the barrel around the drum? Is that what causes the drum to be out of balance?
How do I drain the water?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. The obvious answer is "you did something wrong", but without more information we can't know what. Edit in exactly what you did, and perhaps add some pictures, and we'll have a better chance of helping you.

Comment: There is not much to do wrong with changing the suspension rods. It is very simple and easy!!! I just removed the old ones and installed the new ones. Just as I saw on the YouTube video.

Comment: Again, without more information we won't be able to help you.